# Strange BAD_EXC_ACCESS when declaring a string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring, stringwithformat

Okay, all I am doing is setting an NSString to a value with this code:

```
NSString *stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/%@/trailers?api_key=1523229ded5824dab8bb7840782db266",searchID];
```

This is a string that I then turning into a URL for querying the TMDB database. This line of code gives me a BAD_EXC_ACCESS and it is blowing my mind because using this sort of NSString construction is something I have done thousands of times without a problem.

The one other thing to note is that this line is being executed right after another query call is made. The weird thing is that call makes the stringURL the same way, yet it works fine.

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: what's searchID? a property? where did you alloc and init it?

Comment: it is a number set by an earlier query in the database. It is a readwrite NSInteger property. I can nslog the value of searchID in the same method without a problem so I don't think that is it

Comment: is searchID and object or a primitive (e.g. NSInteger)?

Comment: searchID is int eitherwise there is no problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use %i to log an NSInteger, not %@

Comment: This is the part where the guy stresses how long a way it can take you if you have some basic C knowledge ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the following 
NSString *stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/%d/trailers?api_key=1523229ded5824dab8bb7840782db266",searchID];

Because searchID has NSInteger type and you are using "%@"

Comment: yeah I fixed it from the response above.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an `NSInteger` you need to use **%ld** or you will got a warning, you can also use **%d** and explicitly cast to `int` via *(int)searchID*

Comment: actually xcode only gives me that warning if I am doing OS X programming. With ios, it never warns about NSInteger vs. int, at least not with my version of XCode.

Comment: Yep, but i'm using some shared units for both OS X and iOS, so even when i write for iOS i put %ld for not get warnings later on OS X...

Comment: I see. That makes sense. Well thanks for your input. I knew from the beginning that there was a stupid mistake in this code, I just was completely missing it. StackOverflow for the win, as usual :D